# How do I reference a Sheet.Column in VBA SQL

Tags: excel, database, vba

I created this basic VBA script for the purpose of understanding how to reference a column from a created sheet. In this case, I want to be able to reference the number column of sheet 1 within my sql query. I have attached the complete code I made to test this out. Of course, ws1.number is not working as a field. Is there a correct way to select that column from ws1?

[code](https://pastebin.com/0FDp48tJ)

```
sql = "Select ws1.number " & _
      "from " & ws1 & " as ws1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL text, you can reference the sheet name followed by a `$` in square brackets as if it is a table. If you write the word "Number" into a cell, the following would select every continuous row under that heading:

```
sql = "Select Number" & _
      "FROM [" & ws1.name & "$] as ws1"
```

Note that if you had multiple cells with the text "Number", this will take the first instance of such a cell, searching from left/top to right/bottom.

Comment: I copied and pasted this as the new sql string but it still did not work unfortunately giving me a general odbc error/runtime error. I commented your suggestion out, but that is what I tried. [updated code](https://pastebin.com/vPUzr2P2)

Answer (score 0):

To reference the columns by numbers you will have to set column headers to false in your connection string: `HDR=NO`.  The columns can then be referenced by `F` for field and the number, enclosed by brackets.

```
"SELECT ws1.[F1], ws1.[F2] FROM [" & Worksheets(1).Name & "$] AS ws1"
```

"AS ws1" creates a table alias; to simplify the code.

Comment: I copied and pasted this as the sql string. I added HDR=No to my connection string and removed ws1.[F2] from the query string (since I only have 1 field in my code. I am getting a general odbc error on the query (runtime error). Unfortunately, it doesnt seem to have worked. 

[updated code](https://pastebin.com/vPUzr2P2)

Comment: @rbelliam you might need to specify the address. If you post your code, I will fix it in the morning.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help. The code linked above (via pastebin) is the code I am using to test this. I just changed some names in the connection string but other than that, this is the code I am using. I would post the code directly onto here but since I am a new user on Stack Overflow, I don't have that privilege yet.

Comment: My answer assumed that you were using an `ADOBD` connection.  Sorry, but I don't use `QueryTables`.  I recommend that you close this question and open a new one.  You should post your code and go into some detail about what you are trying to accomplish.  Before and after screenshots are useful.